# I can not use regex to replace text contain "\" character

Tags: java, regex, replace, replaceall, regexp-replace

I have a snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    // replacement text
    String replacement = "Not Set";
    // text
    String text = "Item A \\(XXX\\) Lock"; // text is "Item A\(XXX\)Lock"
    String regex = "\\(XXX\\)"; // regex is "\(XXX\)"
    // result text
    String resultText = text.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
    System.out.println("Result text: " + resultText);
}
```

resultText is "Item A \(XXX\) Lock" -> I can not replace "\(XXX\)" to "Not Set".

Please help me if you know about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The regex language has its own escape sequence on top of the Java string literal escape sequence. So to match a backslash, you need `\\` in the regex and thus `\\\\` in the Java string literal

In this case you could also use [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)

```
text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(regex), Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
```

Comment: Thank for your support

Answer (score 1):

The characters `\`, `(` and `)` all have a special meaning when used in a regular expression.  But you don't want to use them with their special meaning, which means you have to escape them in the regular expression.  That means preceding them with `\`, to tell the regular expression processor not to invoke the special meaning of those characters.

In other words, a regular expression containing `\\` will match `\`, a regular expression containing

`\(` will match `(` and so on.

To match `\(XXX\)`, the regular expression you want will be `\\\(XXX\\\)` - see how there's an extra `\` for each `\`, `(` and `)` that you want to match.  But to specify this regular expression in a Java `String` literal, you need to write `\\` in place of each `\`.  That is, you need to write

`"\\\\\\(XXX\\\\\\)"`.  There are six `\` characters in each little run of them.

```
String regex = "\\\\\\(XXX\\\\\\)"; 
String resultText = text.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
```

Comment: Thank for your support.